# Using .vue files with ts-node

Tags: typescript, vue.js, compilation, ts-node

I'm using ts-node in programmatic way (`require('ts-node').register()`) with Vue for development purposes. This doesn't compile .vue files so there's no option to use them directly. What I'm trying to achieve right now is to plug in to TypeScript compiler (through ts-node) to transform .vue files on the go before importing them to .ts files. However I just can't find the way. Is there even any or no? Or is there possible other way of compiling those .vue files before using them?

Comment: This sounds pretty unusual. What's the context? How/why are you trying to use vue file in what seems like a node (server) app? The usual thing to do is to use .vue files with a bundler like webpack, which allows you to transform .vue files before passing them to TS

Comment: Well it may sound like an overkill but I'm actually developing electron app and wanted to run it in dev mode without compiling whole code. Basically everything is working as it should except Vue's single file components (.vue files) because of course they're not compiled. So that's why I wanted to catch somehow those files before import, compile them and return, replace import path to compiled ones or any other idea. Vue is of course on renderer process' side

Comment: I just hit this, too, trying to get the Mocha Sidebar extension in VS Code to run typescript based tests that import .vue components. Internally it uses ts-node to compile, which works great for .ts files, but basically just need something to compile the vue files beforehand.